# search api to use in external websites

Tags: php, ajax, api, search

I am new to api development, so don't know whether this is feasible or not.

I have a website(`http://www.mysite.com/`) which consists of data and i need to develop an api or somehow use this site's data to use it in another websites.

My requirement is other external websites(`http://www.externalwebsites.com`) need to search the data from my main site (`http://www.mysite.com/`). `http://www.externalwebsites.com/` will send search string to `http://www.mysite.com/` and it will send back result and show them in `http://www.externalwebsites.com/`.

i need to use ajax calls in `http://www.externalwebsites.com/` for searching data, so my question is

1. Is this whole process feasible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use JSONP, supported by default in libraries like jQuery.

http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use SOAP web-service:

http://plutov.by/post/web_service_soap

Comment: SOAP covers a vast number of edge cases. It is usually much more complicated then anything most people need. A JSON or simple XML based RESTful API is usually a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

REST:  http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/REST
SOAP:  http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP
oAuth: http://oauth.net/2/ (this is used by popular sites like Facebook, Google, Yahoo, Twitter)